How to prevent multiple function call in vanilla js
Problem: I'm building a website to visualize sorting algorithms using vanilla JavaScript. When I click the "Sort" button twice, the algorithm starts sorting the same array twice, causing unexpected behavior in the visualization.
What I Have Tried: I suspect this is because the event listener for the "Sort" button is being triggered multiple times, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.


async function handleBubbleSort() {
  const container = document.getElementById("bubble-array-container");
  const elements = container.getElementsByClassName("array-element");

  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  async function step() {
    if (i < elements.length) {
      if (j < elements.length - i - 1) {
        const currentElement = elements[j];
        const nextElement = elements[j + 1];
        currentElement.style.backgroundColor = "var(--current-color)";
        nextElement.style.backgroundColor = "var(--next-color)";
        currentElement.style.color = "black";
        nextElement.style.color = "black";

        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        const currentValue = parseInt(currentElement.innerHTML);
        const nextValue = parseInt(nextElement.innerHTML);

        if (currentValue > nextValue) {
          await swapElements(currentElement, nextElement);
        }

        currentElement.style.backgroundColor = "var(--default-color)";

        nextElement.style.backgroundColor = "var(--default-color)";

        j++;
        await step();
      } else {
        elements[elements.length - i - 1].style.backgroundColor =
          "var(--sorted-color)";
        j = 0;
        i++;
        await step();
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Array Sorted Successfully");
    }
  }
  await step();
}
<div class="sorting-container">
  <h3>Bubble Sort</h3>
  <div class="label-container">
    <div class="label current-element">
      <div class="color-box"></div>
      <span> Current </span>
    </div>
    <div class="label next-element">
      <div class="color-box"></div>
      <span> Next </span>
    </div>
    <div class="label sorted-element">
      <div class="color-box"></div>
      <span>Sorted</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="array-container" id="bubble-array-container"></div>
  <div class="button-group">
    <button class="new-button" onclick="generateNewArray('bubble')">
            Generate New Array
          </button>
    <button class="sort-button" onclick="handleBubbleSort()">Sort</button>
  </div>
</div>




Are you just asking how to disable a button in JavaScript?  Something else?

What do you want to happen instead when the Sort button is clicked twice?

I don't want it to be disable I just want to prevent the function from executing twice.

@SurajR2D2: You could add a global variable to indicate whether or not the logic should execute.  Call it something like isRunning and set it to true when the operation starts and false when the operation completes.  Then in the function just return immediately if the value is true.

You're thinking about it the wrong way.  Don't try to prevent the function from being called.  Instead, in the function's logic, determine what course of action to take.
Create a global flag which indicates if the operation is "currently running".  For example:
let isRunning = false;

In the function, return immediately if the operation is running:
let isRunning = false;

async function handleBubbleSort() {
  if (isRunning) return;

  // the rest of the function...
}

Then simply update that state any time the operation begins or ends:
let isRunning = false;

async function handleBubbleSort() {
  if (isRunning) return;

  isRunning = true;
  // the rest of the function, up to this point:

    } else {
      console.log("Array Sorted Successfully");
      isRunning = false;
    }
  }
  await step();
}

Basically just keep track of whether or not the logic is currently being executed, and conditionally re-execute or not based on that state.
Other functionality you may consider includes:

Disabling the button (you indicated you don't want this but that's likely worth re-visiting)
Providing some additional UX when the user tried to invoke the operation a second time while it's still running (e.g. a message indicating why it won't run again)

